# Can't see anything when the project gets rendered

Tags: modeling

I have the following problem. I' new in Blender and have made a project for my twitch channel. It work's fine and through the camera I can see everthing perfect but when I start rendering it I can't see anything. I'm rendering in EVEE as an FFmpeg Video with WEBM / VP9 (Video Codec) and select RGBA because I want it to be with a transparent backroung. I will send you my project so you maybe can look this up and find the fault. :D
So sad. This took me 3.5 hours and now it doesn't work.

Link (ask for access if necessary):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14IWzrFGePLAuzwzPrGDhRGjTpPdnbW2E?usp=sharing

Greetings
Tim Finmans

Comment: your link asks for an authorization. Are you sure there is not an object that is invisible in preview but visible in render? (check the Outliner)

Comment: Yes, please allow all to access the file in some way

Answer (score 1):

You have the *Output > Post Processing > Sequencer* option enabled, therefore it will take the strip that you have in your video sequencer into account. So either delete the strip or disable the option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked finde for me :D I'm happy :)

Comment: Do you maybe also have a tip how I can render this with transparent backround. I have selected FFmpeg Video and Quicktime with WEBM / VP9. I want to use the file in OBS as a video when it#S finished. Would be very kind. :D

Comment: Quicktime should have an alpha option, maybe check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArJCsLBGByI